# Sculptris-style sphere as default in sculpt mode

Tags: modeling

Thanks for any help on my very basic problem. Opening Blender in **Sculpt mode for the first time, there was a "Sculptris-like" sphere that I cannot seem to get back to or add.** **I want to work with this type of default as a starting point.**
I can add a mesh sphere, subdivide and use sculpt mode, but this isn't the same kind of modelling. When adding a "Metaball", because it isn't a mesh (?), I cannot use sculpt mode. 
I could completely uninstall/reinstall Blender (maybe),and set it as a default in preferences, but that is a work around that leaves me ignorant of what I need to know. I have my reasons for wanting to do this in Blender and not Sculptris.

I am using a Mac running Mojave.
Thanks,
Brett

Comment: Do you mean an icosphere?

Comment: Or maybe sphere from cube? Please add a picture of it.

Comment: Instead of trying to delete your post, please add the answer that you've found instead so others that have the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recreate the default "Quad Sphere"from the Sculpting default start-up file.

1. Install Add-On "Mesh: Extra Objects"
2. Add a Rounded Cube, with the following parameters (in the screenshot).
3. Add a Subdivision Surface modifier with 4 levels (CTRL + 4) and Apply it.
4. Change the dimensions to 2.57m cubed
5. Apply the scale so it is 1 uniformly.

I also took a default Cube, and subdivided (CTRL + 5) it and sized it appropriately, and got an imperfect result, however, the vertex count was identifical to the default Quad Sphere.

As you can see, it seems that I have recreated it perfectly (with the Rounded Cube), at least according to my eyes, and the statistics (24,578 verts, etc).

Feel free to critique and such.

[image]create new rounded cube

[image]parameters for creating the cube

[image]adjust the size, then apply the scale

[image]side by side comparison

[image]stats for newly created rounded cube

[image]stats for default Quad Sphere